# Current time equal or less than in MySQL at 24 hour cycle

Tags: mysql, current-time

What's the best way to search less than current time at 24 hour cycle?

**Database**

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | time     | name      |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | 07:00:00 | Breakfast |
|  2 | 12:00:00 | Lunch     |
|  3 | 18:00:00 | Dinner    |
|  4 | 21:00:00 | Supper    |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

**My Solution**

When the current time is 15:00:00

```
SELECT * FROM schedules where time < CURRENT_TIME() ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
+----+----------+-------+
| id | time     | name  |
+----+----------+-------+
|  2 | 12:00:00 | Lunch |
+----+----------+-------+
```

**But my solution not Work at 02:00:00**

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | time     | name  |
+----+----------+-------+
+----+----------+-------+
```

**How to searching 02:00:00 and the result is:**

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | time     | name   |
+----+----------+--------+
|  4 | 21:00:00 | Supper |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Is 12:00PM exact lunch time or breakfast?

Comment: 12:00PM is lunch time ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force include the last row in result using `union all`:

```
(
    -- when current time is gte 07:00
    select *
    from schedules
    where time <= current_time()
    order by time desc
    limit 1
)
union all
(
    -- union last row if no matching row exists for previous query
    select *
    from schedules
    where not exists (
        select *
        from schedules
        where time <= current_time()
    )
    order by time desc
    limit 1
)
```